# Microsoft. Office.interop. Excel dll exception

Tags: asp.net, exception, excel-interop

In localhost, it is working properly with dll and its assemblies but when I am hosting my website at that time it is showing me exception " Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified"
Is anyone having solution of this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [So I really can't use Excel Object Model to be used server-side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215664/so-i-really-cant-use-excel-object-model-to-be-used-server-side)

Answer (score 0):

you juste need to include the  bin file générated in the project

Comment: check that the imported dll are in the folder, if you dont find them all put they in the bin folder manually